# How to rotate an SKShapeNode line around its bottom point

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm confused on how to rotate a line (SKShapeNode) around it's bottom point (begin point, here), think of a clock here.

I have the following, but it doesn't seem to be rotating as expected.

```
    public let line = SKShapeNode()
    private let linePath = CGMutablePath()

    init(begin: CGPoint, end: CGPoint) {
        self.begin = begin
        self.end = end


        linePath.move(to: begin)
        linePath.addLine(to: end)

        line.path = linePath
        line.strokeColor = UIColor.black
        line.lineWidth = 3
        SceneCoordinator.shared.gameScene.addChild(line)
    }


    public func rotate(angle: Double) {
         var transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(angle))
         line.path = linePath.mutableCopy(using: &transform)

    }
```

Comment: Is it not possible to accomplish both these aspects? I'm trying to rotate around the bottom point but also be able to capture what the top point is. I'm sorry I haven't done much with shapes and paths so I'm a bit unexperienced here.

Comment: What I'm essentially trying to do is stack lines on top of each other and any which random line may be rotated. So I'm trying to figure out how to rotate along the bottom point, but also find the top point so that I know where to place the next line. The end result would look like some random zig zag'd line

Comment: Replacing your  code with my suggested answer and then asking another question makes this Q&A  unintelleible for future readers. – Please keep your original question (so that the answer makes sense). You can then add *additional* information.

Comment: My bad, my intentions were to edit it and ask if I was understanding you correct because I didn't want to copy and paste a function into the comments.

Comment: I have added something to the answer which might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  function rotates the path around the
shapes `position` (which is `(0, 0)` by default) and not around the starting point of the line as intended.

To solve the problem, create the shape with a  position equal to the starting
point of the line, and with a line  relative to that point:

```
linePath.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
linePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: end.x - begin.x, y: end.y - begin.y))
line.path = linePath
line.position = begin
// ...
SceneCoordinator.shared.gameScene.addChild(line)
```

Note that instead of transforming the path you can rotate the node:

```
line.zRotation = angle
```

or with animation:

```
line.run(SKAction.rotate(toAngle: angle, duration: 0.2))
```

You can compute the position of the endpoint in the scene's
coordinate system with

```
let endPos = line.convert(CGPoint(x: end.x - begin.x, y: end.y - begin.y), to: line.scene!)
```